# Move everything to SD card on Android Virtual Device (Emulator)

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, android-emulator, emulators

I need to do a strange task. I want to move whole android system to external SD card on Android Virtual Device. I need to do this, because android emulator, emulates SD commands, only for external card image. And I want to get SD commands trace, during Android Virtual Device usage.

To be more precise: I want to move at least /system and /data folders to external storage. In such way, that system could still work fine =)

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move some of system folders (/system or /data), to external emulated SD card, you need to do following:

1. Firstly, /data contents (for example) should be placed on sdcard. Initially they are loaded by emulator from userdata.img file.
   So you need to copy userdata.img `($EMUPATH/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a/userdata.img)` contents to `sdcard.iso`. `$> dd if=userdata.img of=sdcard.iso`
2. I assume, that android virtual device is created. To change boot configuration, you will need to change `fstab.goldfish` file on `ramdisk.img`. If it is Android 4.4 AVD, then `ramdisk.img` could also be find at `$EMUPATH/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a/`

- Create a temporary folder, say ramdisk-ext `$ mkdir ramdisk-ext`
- Change directory to ramdisk-ext `$ cd ramdisk-ext`
- Extract the ramdisk.cpio in the ramdisk-ext folder `$ gunzip -dcv ../ramdisk.img | cpio -idm`
- Modify fstab.goldfish `$ gedit fstab.goldfish` in such way:

  - String #6 from `"/dev/block/mtdblock1    /data ..."` to `"/dev/block/mmcblk0    /data ..."`
- Create new ramdisk `$ find . | cpio -H newc -o | gzip -9 >../ramdisk_new.img`

2. Everything is done, now you need to start the emulator, with your new ramdisk and custom sdcard:`$ ./emulator -avd $AVDNAME -sdcard sdcard.iso -ramdisk $EMUPATH/system-images/android-19/armeabi-v7a/ramdisk_new.img`

P.S. Notice that in this example you can move only one of such folders (/system or /data). Maybe it could be changed, by creating sdcard image with several partitions.